# Export table records with BLOB to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, blob

There are records in MySQL database with fields whose type is BLOB. I export the records to JSON in MySQL workbench.
The resulting JSON file consists of records in the following format :

```
   [{
        'ID : 1,
        'field: 75945969799,
        'BLOBField' : ?
    }]
```

The values of the BLOB column are in JSON format (when viewed in MySQL). My goal is to cause BLOB values to be in JSON format instead of '?'.
How do i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: you have to use hexadecimal format for BLOB for exporting

Comment: Can you explain how to convert BLOB fields to hexa in MySQL? When I choose BLOB value and choose : " Save value to File"  i succeed to save it in JSON format. However, i don't understand how to save the entire table in JSON format including the BLOB fields.